# preg_match match a word all that starts and ends with

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to match all the characters that starts after `Condition is\s` and and ends with either `.` or a `,`

```
$pattern = "/Condition is\s([a-zA-Z_-]+)/";
$string = "Condition is test_name. some test";
$string1 = "Condition is test-hello-name, some test";
preg_match($pattern,$string,$match);
Output:
Array ( [0] => Condition is test_name [1] => test_name )
preg_match($pattern,$string,$match);
Output:
Array ( [0] => Condition is test-hello-name [1] => test-hello-name )
```

Above code is working but if  I enter space it will not work.

`test-name`

I tried pattern `$pattern = "/Condition is\s([a-zA-Z_- ]+)/";`

with space it gives an error

Comment: The error in the last patter is the unscape `-` at the end `([a-zA-Z_\- ]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this pattern:

```regex
\bCondition is\s+([^.,]+)
```

Sample script:

```php
$string = "Condition is test_name. some test";
preg_match_all("/\bCondition is\s+([^.,]+)/", $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];  // test_name
```

Comment: Thanks,But I want to use preg_match

Comment: It is basically the same function, nothing wrong with my answer.